# Query with columns from 4 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Can anyone who knows SQL, specifically the flavor used in Microsoft Access 2013, tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
SELECT custid, custname, ordno, itemno, itemname
FROM cust
INNER JOIN order
ON cust.custid = order.custid
INNER JOIN orderitems
ON order.ordno = orderitems.ordno
INNER JOIN inv
ON orderitems.itemno = inv.itemno;
```

I've already read other, similar questions, and tried the methods they used in their solutions, but I'm getting a "Syntax error in FROM clause.", almost no matter what I try.

`*   *   *`

SOLUTION: Thanks for the replies! In addition to adding square brackets around "order" and using TableName.ColumnName syntax in SELECT, I had to use parentheses for my multiple INNER JOINs. Here is the fixed code:

```
SELECT cust.custid, cust.custname, [order].ordno, orderitems.itemno, inv.itemname
FROM ((cust
INNER JOIN [order]
ON cust.custid = [order].custid)
INNER JOIN orderitems
ON [order].ordno = orderitems.ordno)
INNER JOIN inv
ON orderitems.itemno = inv.itemno;
```

Comment: May or may not be your problem, but I'd not use the table name `order`  unescaped (which may conflict with `ORDER BY`). You may want to try `[order]`.

Comment: The issue might be that `order` is a keyword. You might have to surround it with `[]` so it's `[order]`. The brackets allow escaping of column names.

Comment: The problem is the use of `order` which is an SQL reserved keyword.  If you have to use that table name, then bracket it:  `[order]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cust.custid   --<-- Use two part name here 
      ,cust.custname
      ,[order].ordno
      ,orderitems.itemno   --<-- Only guessing here use the correct table name
      ,inv.itemname        --<-- Only guessing here use the correct table name
FROM cust
INNER JOIN [order]
ON cust.custid = [order].custid   --<-- used square brackets [] around ORDER as it is
INNER JOIN orderitems                  -- a key word.
ON [order].ordno = orderitems.ordno
INNER JOIN inv
ON orderitems.itemno = inv.itemno;
```

In your Select Statament you need to use Two Part name i.e  `TableName.ColumnName` since these column can exist in more than one Tables in your FROM clause you need to tell sql server that columns in your select coming from which table in your from clause.

Comment: Thank you, this helps, but now I'm getting the following error:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
    'cust.custid = [order].custid
    INNER JOIN orderitems
    ON [order].ordno = orderitems.ordno
    INNER JOIN inv
    ON orderitems.itemno = inv.itemn'.